# How to display banners equally?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banner

I have a website with an admin session where a admin can add a banner. The banner entity has a `int ClickLimit` and a `int VisualizationLimit`. So every time this banner is displayed i increment +1 to the `VisualizationLimit` and the same for the click.

The problem is that i need some kind of **FIFO queue**. On the logic above it will not work, because if a user clicks 10 times and then some admin adds a new banner, the `int ClickLimit` and a `int VisualizationLimit` will be 0 for the new banner, so this banner will be displayed 9 times and the older banner will not be displayed.

**Goals:**
I need to show the banners equally, not randomly. Like a FIFO queue, when the less viewed banner is displayed, it will go to the end of the queue.

I tried to find some pattern to implement it but without lucky. Whats the best solution to this situation?

Comment: And what do you want to achieve? Whats the desired outcome?

Comment: @Romias I´ve edit OP

Comment: You can display serveral banners simultaneously?

Comment: @Romias no, just one at time in one place of the Layout page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just add a `'LastViewed'` on the banner entity. You can show whatever hasn't been viewed recently.

Just increment `ViewCount` and set `LastViewed` time on the entity when it is viewed and then **show whatever has the oldest date**.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping a temporary counter (List) in am in-memory cache (Shared cache if load balancing).

So you could store something in cache:

```
imagecount-image1:19
imagecount-image2:17
imagecount-image3:18
    ^
use a prefix so you can identify these as part of the same set.
```

Each time you display an image increment the cached count, and DB count. (This way the DB Count is the lifetime count) the cache can then be deleted when a new image is added, so all the images will get displayed fairly.

You will need some code to manage the cache, so that you can work with a list of imageCounters rather than dealing with each one individual.

*Just a suggestion - hope it helps*

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a sequencing problem. For instance, if you have a list of banners in memory, you could determine which to show by:

```
var banner = banners.OrderBy (_ => _.VisualizationLimit).First ();
```

Then you'll want to increment your values and update your database, or wherever you're persisting your information.

If my assumption is incorrect that you don't already have your list of banners, then you'll need to query them from your database. This presents an interesting concurrency problem that could occur in high-traffic sites...

A typical scenario might be to load the next banner based off a `group by/having` clause where you look for the smallest VisualizationLimit banner, then increment those values in memory, and update your database. The potential problem here is that under heavy load, the server may swap CPU time with another thread BEFORE you've updated your database. Now you're loading the same banner multiple times based on stale information.

Without writing a book of an answer, if you have a low-traffic site then you probably won't have to worry much about concurrency. If you are expecting a large amount of traffic then you might want to take this under consideration and plan your queries and updates appropriately or your numbers may not be accurate.

**Edit**: After re-reading your problem, it seems that you DON'T want to display banners repeatedly until they've caught up visually. In this case, you could add a timestamp to the table in your database and query the banner that hasn't been viewed for the longest. The same principles above still apply, including the potential concurrency issues.

Hope this helps and good luck!